# Unetbootin not recognising USB drive for Ubuntu installation

Tags: usb, unetbootin

I'm trying to create a Live Ubuntu installer on a USB, using Unetbootin (on a Mac running OSX Yosemite). I followed instructions online and formatted my USB with Disk Utility, to `MS-DOS(FAT)` format and GUID Partition scheme. However, Unetbooting still does not recognise the USB (i.e. nothing is listed under the `Drive` field).

Something which may be of relevance: my Disk Utility doesn't give me the option to select partition scheme when I format with the `Erase` tab. Therefore I first formatted the USB to `MS-DOS(FAT)` format, and then I created a single partition with `GUID Partition` scheme and `MS-DOS(FAT)` format.

[image]

[image: SanDisk Cruzer U Media]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you should stick with one mode, Bios/MBR or gpt

Comment: As far as I know, yes. My Disk Utility only gives me the MS-DOS(FAT) option (as well as a bunch of other, unrelated options like Journaled). So I assume this is FAT32...?

Comment: no, probably is means MBR partitioning

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for all the help with this. After a few days of trying to figure it out, I couldn't resolve the problem so I ended up using a different 3rd party software - Etcher - to create a live Ubuntu installer on USB. I would recommend it to anyone who can't get Unetbootin working.

Comment: agree.  same problem here on Windows 10, not seeing an empty, just formatted, FAT32 USB.  Unetbootin has _tons_ of questions about not recognizing usb disks.  Shame they do nothing much about them.  Honestly, if they can't get something simple like this right, how much do you trust them that their system will actually succeed at booting, considering how tricky UEFI-based systems are to boot Linux with?